# Remove elements from Array that are duplicates if compared to elements in another Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, unity-game-engine

I have the SuperClass `Tile` extended in many SubClassess such as `GroundTile`, `WallTile`, `TrapTile` etc..
In another Class, lets call it `Main`, i can use a function that retrieves me all instances of those classes as an array.

```
Main(){  
  void MyFunctionThatDoesThings(){
    GroundTile[] grounds = FindObjectsOfType<GroundTile>();
    WallTile[] walls = FindObjectsOfType<WallTile>();
    // ... *same code but for other Classes* ...
    Tile[] tiles = FindObjectsOfType<Tile>();
    // ... etc
  }
}
```

What I need to do is to filter from `tiles` array the elements that are not already present in the other arrays.
Is there a way (or a Linq method) to do this other than Looping through the `tiles` array, checking if the current element is equal to any element in the other arrays, and if not keep it otherwise delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already storing each array in it's own variable as you show above, then you can filter out the other arrays using the `Except()` extension method (which you get from `using System.Linq;`).

Then you can just do something like:

```
GroundTile[] grounds = FindObjectsOfType<GroundTile>();
WallTile[] walls = FindObjectsOfType<WallTile>();
TrapTile[] traps = FindObjectsOfType<TrapTile>();

Tile[] tiles = FindObjectsOfType<Tile>()
    .Except(traps)
    .Except(walls)
    .Except(grounds)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is almost the same as @Sir Rufo's answer. And it's even "cleaner" to be read. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tile[] tiles = FindObjectsOfType<Tile>().Except(
    Enumerable.Empty<Tile>()
        .Concat( grounds )
        ...
        .Concat( walls ) ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `grounds.Concat`... ?

Answer (score 0):

This might do as an example if I understood correctly:

```
            List<int> l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 };
            List<int> s = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            var result = s.Where(x => l.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using LINQ.
Assuming you have an ID to identify a particular object.

```
GroundTile[] grounds = FindObjectsOfType<GroundTile>();
WallTile[] walls = FindObjectsOfType<WallTile>();
// ... *same code but for other Classes* ...
Tile[] tiles = FindObjectsOfType<Tile>();

var existingTiles = grounds.Union(walls);

tiles = tiles.Where(t => existingTiles.All(e => e.ID != t.ID)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why is converting to List needed?

Comment: True. It is not required. Thanks for pointing out. I will update.

Comment: You should use All instead of Any

Comment: I understand your logic, and it should work. but i get this error: `CS1929: Type 'GroundTile[]' does not contain a member 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union<WallTile>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<WallTile>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WallTile>)' requires an instance of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WallTile>' `

Comment: @DamianoCaprari Did you add `using System.Linq`?
`Union` is extension method in `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: Yes i'm using System.Linq.
I guess it does not like to add arrays of different types?
Anyway i used @Rufus L's answer and that works fine. Thank you anyway.